# Typed struct contains typed function that takes this typed struct as an argument

Tags: c, structure, typedef

Is it wrong at all and there is no way, or i have to do it somewhat else?

For example:

```
typedef void (*UserFunc)(Test *tx);

typedef struct{
int a;
char b;
UserFunc func;
} Test;
```

i get this error:

```
c.c:5:26: error: unknown type name ‘Test’
 typedef void (*UserFunc)(Test *tx);
                          ^~~~
c.c:10:1: error: unknown type name ‘UserFunc’
 UserFunc func;
 ^~~~~~~~
```

When i move down function typedef:

```
typedef struct{
int a;
char b;
UserFunc func;
} Test;

typedef void (*UserFunc)(Test *tx);
```

I get:

```
c.c:8:1: error: unknown type name ‘UserFunc’
 UserFunc func;
 ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please go through forward deceleration. I think it will help you to figure out the issue

Comment: Thank you! Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare Test first, and define it later :

```
typedef struct Test Test;

typedef void (*UserFunc)(Test *tx);

typedef struct Test {
    int      a;
    char     b;
    UserFunc func;
} Test;
```